# what 'P' s mean in bezier curve equation

Tags: geometry

I have equation

[image: bezier cubic curve]

As much I know, I have four points lets say A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2), C(x3,y3), D(x4, y4). How these 'P' are related to these set of points. And what might a Cubic Bézier curves be for the this (A, B, C, D) given set of points.

[UPDATE]

Having problem uploading image, but image somewhat looks like this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142556/algorithm-to-add-color-in-bezier-curves

Regards,

Comment: The $P_0$, $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ are the points A, B, C, D. If you let $t=0$ you get $B(0)=P_0$; if you let $t=1$ you get $B(1)=P_3$ so the curve starts at the initial point and finishes at the last.

Comment: @Henry i am looking to get equation in two variables $x$ and $y$ (cubic equation). and where does this variable $t$ come in play.

Comment: You *really* do not want to do that.  You can try solving $x = (1-t)^3 x_1 + 3(1-t)^2 t x_2 + 3(1-t) t^2 x_3 +  t^3 x_4$ for $t$ in terms of $x$ as a [cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots) and then substitute that value of $t$ into $y = (1-t)^3 y_1 + 3(1-t)^2 t y_2 + 3(1-t) t^2 y_3 +  t^3 y_4$ but you will get into such a mess that it will not have helped.  The relationship between $x$ and $y$ is not in general cubic, just the relations between each of them and $t$.

Comment: @Henry thanks, i think in understand. Certainly, those two equations were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what relationship you want your points $A$ to $D$ to have to the spline. It may be that you want them to have exactly the relationship to the splines that the points $P_0$ to $P_3$ have, which is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves). Strangely, the equation in your question looks as if you copied it from there, but in that case you'd have to explain what part of the explanation there of what $P_0$ to $P_3$ mean you don't understand, and what you want your points $A$ to $D$ to mean instead.

Comment: shouldn't the equation be like $y=Px^3+Qx^2+ ...$ so that i could plot graph. But what i  have i set of points $P0-P3$ . How P's come in equation. Is it complex equation?

Comment: @experimentX: Your equation gives $y$ in terms of $x$. The equation in the question give $x$ and $y$ in terms of a parameter $t$. That is, $B(t)$ is a vector $(x(t),y(t))$ that traces a Bézier curve as you vary $t$ from $0$ to $1$. In particular, $B(0)=P_0$ and $B(1)=P_3$. This can't easily be put into the form $y(x)$ that you're interested in, because that would require solving the cubic $x(t)$ for $t$ and substituting into $y(t)$; the result would be pretty ugly and unhelpful. And no, it's not a complex equation, just an equation involving two-dimensional vectors.

Comment: thanks it was helpful ... just someone had posted and script for printing this function, i was just wondering how could i improve it. see the result in the updated section.